X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation) / Mesa libs / X / video encoding bugged / broken on FreeBSD 14.1
I'm running FreeBSD 14.1 right now and I suspect that the Mesa libs that I have installed on the system are bugged or maybe I have some misconfiguration,because when I do :
# glxinfo | grep Mesa

I get the error that you see on the title and smplayer/mpv/vlc doesn't work at all. Anyway,this is the context in which the error happens :
I have 3 GPUS :
1)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]




01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB]
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 High Definition Audio Controller




02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 [GeForce RTX 2080 Ti]
02:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 High Definition Audio Controller
02:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 USB 3.1 Host Controller
02:00.3 Serial bus controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 USB Type-C UCSI Controller

I'm not using any xorg.conf.
nano /etc/rc.conf :

kld_list="nvidia-modeset nvidia-drm linux i915kms ext2fs"

nano /boot/loader.conf :
pptdevs="1/0/0 1/0/1 2/0/0 2/0/1 2/0/2 2/0/3 4/0/0"
hw.nvidiadrm.modeset=1

This is where the problem is :
[marietto@marietto ~]==> glxinfo | grep Mesa

X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  50
  Current serial number in output stream:  51

I've installed the following packages :
# pkg install xf86-video-intel nvidia-drm-kmod drm-kmod nvidia-driver

I've also tried to check if I had the same error by removing the xf86-video-intel and using the i915kms driver with Xorg :
# pkg remove xf86-video-intel
# nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Section "Device"
  Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
  Driver      "i915kms"
EndSection

But I've got the same error. Maybe it is a Mesa bug.
What's one consequence of this "bug" ? this one :
==> scrcpy --tcpip=192.168.1.3:5555

scrcpy 2.7 <https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy>
INFO: Connecting to 192.168.1.3:5555...
INFO: Connected to 192.168.1.3:5555
/usr/local/share/scrcpy/scrcpy-server: 1 file pushed, 0 skipped. 34.1 MB/s (71200 bytes in 0.002s)
[server] INFO: Device: [samsung] samsung SM-N9005 (Android 9)
[server] WARN: Audio disabled: it is not supported before Android 11

X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  147
  Current serial number in output stream:  148

